# searching for a "calendar framework" to use

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

Good day all.
I've involved in a nice project where I will code a sort of CRM for a learning centre.

They are already using "excell" to keep track of the courses/professors/rooms and they used to organize events on a "week-day" basis, for example, let's say that the marketing lession is every friday, at 12:00, they have an excell sheet where in the first column, there are the weekdays, then the other columns are the dates of the year which are that day, let's assume friday:

```
               |       JANUARY         ||      FEBRUARY    ||
    FRIDAY     | 3 | 10 | 17 | 24 | 31 || 7 | 14 | 21 | 28 || ....
8:00 - 10:00   | A | A  | A  | A  |    ||   |    |    |    || ....
10:00 - 12:00  |   |    | B  | B  | B  || B |    |    |    || ....
12:00 - 14:00  | C | C  |    |    |    || C | C  |    |    || ....
...
```

my question is, given this kind of "view" anyone knows a calendar (plugin, framework, standalone...), written in PHP or javascript (or similar, read jquery or else)?

I would like an help to be pointed in the right direction, just tu prevent to write down the  all calendar and reinvent the wheel.

i've given an eye on some calendar written in jquery and to php-calendar, but i got any luck...
if someone knows the way...

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT* 
I have found this image on shuterstock, which rapresent the way I would like this calendar.

http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-88297315/stock-vector-vector-year-calendar-month-in-a-column-weekdays-aligned-horizontally-rounded-cells-rounded.html

Comment: also, if someone has the "name" of this view, which is not the week view, but something like "weekday horizontal view" or something... well, something i could seaerch on the web i mean. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arshaw fullCalender JS plugin,  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
It has different views monthly , weekly and daily. you will need weekly view for your website. or you can show all the views at same time

Regards.

Comment: nice plugin, but it hasn't nothing more than the normal views all other calendars have, but there is a nice drag and drop feature, which probably i would like to implement in the application. thanks anyway.